# Black-Box Matrix Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a black box operation, i.e. you don't have access to the entries of $A$. Suppose further that $A$ is sparse so that computing $Ax$ is an $O(n)$ operation. Devise a way to compute $A^{\star}x$ for any vector $x$ so that this operation is $O(n)$.

A naive way of computing this is via the following observation:

$$\langle A^{\star}x,e_i\rangle=\langle x,Ae_i\rangle=(A^{\star}x)_{i}$$

Since we know how to compute $Ae_i$, we are good. The cost of computing $(A^{\star}x)_i$ is the cost of picking out the $i$th element of $Ae_i$ and multiplying by $x_i$ ($O(1)$) plus the cost of computing $Ae_i$ $(O(n))$ to lead to a computation that is $O(n)$. But this must be done FOR EVERY $i$, so the total computation is $O(n^2)$. Furthermore, this approach amounts to pretty much reconstructing ALL the entries of $A$ ($Ae_i$ is simply the $i$th column of $A$), and thus in a sense, you're kicking out its sparsity and thus the performance drop.

Or is this even possible and if it's impossible, is there a way to prove it? In theory, I guess you'd need to know what the sparsity pattern is ahead of time in order to preserve the linear cost, correct?

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is not possible, considering that the matrix has real entries and the sparsity can be any constant factor of $n$. The reason is that *any* sparsity pattern can result in the same value of $(Ax)_i$, so it does not look like that operation can be sufficiently informative. Maybe you can do better than $n^2$, though.